# trying to play a video file but can't

Tags: mac, video

i'm trying to play a video file but it says: 'there is no default application specified to open the document "vmt-pbboy-xvid.r02"' I was going to download xvid but it's not available for Mac, and i only have Mac computer. i don't know what to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

r02 is a RAR split archive, you will have to unpack the file, starting with the **first** archive (vmt-pbboy-xvid.rar).

You can use this program to extract the archive:

> **[UnRarX](http://www.unrarx.com/)** is a Mac OS X application that allows you to expand
>   rar archives and restore corrupted or
>   missing archives using par2.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that filename I suspect the file is not a video - it looks to be part of a multi-part rar archive (which in turn contains the video file). You need to find all the other parts of the archive so you can extract its contents using a rar compatible archive tool.